# VS 2012 CRM Explorer can't connect to Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm-2013

UPDATE: We've determined this to be the result of an issue in our CRM2013 environment, although we haven't been able to identify the issue. We installed a new CRM2013 instance, migrated our organization and solutions, and everything works as expected in the new CRM2013 environment.

ORIGINAL POST: I'm unable to connect to an on-premises instance of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 using CRM Explorer in Visual Studio Pro 2012. When Connect to Dynamics CRM Server is selected from the Tools menu the connect dialog presents and operates normally until the Organization is selected, at which point the dialog closes before a Solution is selected and without selecting Ok or Cancel. No error message is presented.

I've tried starting VS with the /log switch but there are no error messages in the logfile.

I've successfully connected to a CRM 2011 on-premises instance, so the VS Studio install appears to be correct.

At this point I'm wondering if there's a bug in CRM 2013 or an issue with this particular install.

The Dynamics SDK is version 6.10, May 2014. 
Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.061030.00 Update 4
Crm 2013  Service Pack 1 (SP1) (6.1.0.581) (DB 6.1.0.581)

Comment: I am just throwing a stone in dark. Try to run VS as Administrator. Sometimes it solves the problems. Shift Key + Right Click on VS Icon >  Run As Administrator.