# dynamics crm 2013(or 2011) hosted in azure vm, org svc url is different outside vs returned by service

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, dynamics-crm-2013

I am unable to connect to CRM Server using the SDK(VS2012 crashes when one of the Org is selected from drop down, similar to below person ).
[VS 2012 CRM Explorer can't connect to Dynamics CRM 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246501/vs-2012-crm-explorer-cant-connect-to-dynamics-crm-2013).
But I was able to connect using the XRMToolbox code since I was able to step through and solve bad url problems encountered during connection.

My CRM server is hosted inside Azure VM. Its internet facing url is pkcmr2.cloudapp.net:5555 , but its internal url is simply "pkcmr2:5555".

I think this may be causing problem(as I inferred while working through connecting to this CRM server using Microsoft.XRM library).

One of the solutions I can think of is, if I can make internal url to be same as external, how do I do it, any direction is appreciated?

Internet facing App Url: http://pkcrm2.cloudapp.net:5555/org1/main.aspx

Discovery Service
http://pkcrm2:5555/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc

Organization Service
http://pkcrm2:5555/org1/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc

Organization Data Service
http://pkcrm2:5555/org1/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM OnPremise hosted on Azure is currently not a supported configuration

Comment: is it not possible to have the CRM app available on say pkcrm2.XYZpk.com, instead of pkcrm2.cloudapp.net , and my guess is that we install a custom domain inside my azure network called as XYZpk [maybe xyzpk.local) and make CRM Server part of this xyzpk.local domain? (sorry I am a complete newbie when it comes to networking concepts)